# JS - Programmatically open DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to open DevTools programmatically?

```js
function() {
    // Code  for Open DevTools
};
```

Comment: You CANNOT open devtools with code. This is by design because it would be a security hole. Read the post I linked (where they ask the same question and get the same answer)